# Why is my POST request repeating every 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

My client is sending 1 POST request, but for some reason my server is processing it repeatedly every 2 minutes. Why is it doing this?

When I run my code and click the submit button from the client, the client console outputs ONE time:

```
6/1/2018 @ 13:8:29 sendsettings request sent"
```

But the server console will output:

```
6/01/2018 @ 13:08:29 sendsettings request received
6/01/2018 @ 13:08:29: ---INTRUDER ALERT---
6/01/2018 @ 13:10:29 sendsettings request received
6/01/2018 @ 13:10:29: ---INTRUDER ALERT---
6/01/2018 @ 13:12:29 sendsettings request received
6/01/2018 @ 13:12:29: ---INTRUDER ALERT---
6/01/2018 @ 13:14:29 sendsettings request received
6/01/2018 @ 13:14:29: ---INTRUDER ALERT---
```

etc...

Here is simplified version of my client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="inputs">
            Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password"> 
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("submit").onclick = submitInfoToServer;

            var xhttpPost = new XMLHttpRequest();

            function submitInfoToServer() {

                xhttpPost.open("POST", "/sendSettings", true);

                var password = document.getElementById("password").value

                var sendString = JSON.stringify({
                        password: password
                    });

                var currentdate = new Date(); 
                var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                            + ((currentdate.getMonth()+1))  + "/" 
                            + (currentdate.getFullYear()) + " @ "  
                            + (currentdate.getHours()) + ":"  
                            + (currentdate.getMinutes()) + ":" 
                            + (currentdate.getSeconds());

                console.log(datetime + ' sendsettings request sent')
                xhttpPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                xhttpPost.send(sendString);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The simplified server code is:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var https = require('https')
var json = require('express-json')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))

app.post('/sendSettings', function(request, response) {

    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + pad((currentdate.getMonth()+1))  + "/" 
                + pad(currentdate.getFullYear()) + " @ "  
                + pad(currentdate.getHours()) + ":"  
                + pad(currentdate.getMinutes()) + ":" 
                + pad(currentdate.getSeconds());

    console.log(datetime + ' sendsettings request received')

    if(request.body.password == 'password')
        console.log(datetime + ': correct password')
    else
        console.log(datetime + ': ---INTRUDER ALERT---')

})
```

Comment: You don't seem to be sending a response to the post...

Comment: oh, didn't realize I needed to do that. Would just putting response.send() at the end of the POST code solve it?

Comment: It will help; not sure if there are other problems, but every express end point has to send a response at some point, or pass on to the rest of the chain.

Comment: Not sure what kind of behavior this would cause, but you should not use `type="submit"` but `type="button"` or simply using `<button>` when placed outside of a form. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but if anyone comes to this: The default timeout for a request in Node.js is 2 minutes. You are not sending any response back from your server.

Fix the server script to send something back (eg: res.send('something')) and this will stop happening.